# Cannot extend C: partition, "Extend Volume" grayed out

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

My disk Partition C is almost full so I am trying to increase it's size but Windows is not allowing me to do so in spite having 195GB unallocated space!

[image: Diskmgmt screenshot]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The unallocated space is in the wrong place. You may only extend a partition
*downwards*, so this space must *follow* the partition of C.

You need to boot a partition editor, since you cannot move C while also booting
from it. Then you will need to move E down to overwrite the unallocated space.
This will move this space between D and E.
Repeat this for D to have the unallocated space follow C.

You should then boot into Windows and resize C. It is best to resize Windows
using Windows. The bootable partition editor might possibly make a mistake
when handling sensitive Windows files.

This operation is dangerous, in the sense that a mistake can make the disk
unbootable. It is best to take a backup image of the disk and have a bootable
media of the backup program that can restore it in case of a severe problem
(and to test it before starting).